# Defining number set sequences based on the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

The Fundamental theorem of arithmetic gives a natural way to write natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ uniquely in terms of products in powers of primes:

$$N = 2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5} \ldots $$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$  with $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$

This can be generalized to rational numbers:

$$N = 2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5} \ldots $$ for all $N \in \mathbb{Q}$  with $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

Can this scheme be generalized on more ways?

For example, is not clear that algebraic irrationals are contained in the set of

$$N = 2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5} \ldots $$ with $n_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

but clearly this set is contained in the algebraic irrationals union rationals.

In a parallel fashion, if we take imaginary unit $i$ as a new element of the prime set, we can rotate in any dense direction in the complex plane by taking all rational exponents

One in principle could define a family of sets in a recursive way:

$$\mathbb{T}_{i+1} = \big\{ N = 2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5} \ldots  n_j \in \mathbb{T}_i  \big \} $$

with $\mathbb{T}_0 = \mathbb{Z}$

And ask, do transcendental numbers like $\pi$ or $e$ belong to $\mathbb{T}_i$ for some $i$?

Comment: I am not giving you a solution but it can be done using programing. Wolfram alpha and other sites are best to check your predictions.

Comment: Also the smallest field $F$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and closed under $x \mapsto x^{1/m}$ for every $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ is well-known, this is the largest [radical extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension) of $\mathbb{Q}$, whose Galois group is the largest solvable quotient group of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. That is $F$ is the field containing all the towers of cyclic extensions of the full cyclotomic field $\bigcup_n \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$.